# Scheduled Job & Balloon tip

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for a way to run a job on a schedule and also alert the user to that running job. Specifically, I am using PowerShell to manage a computer lab scenario, and between sessions I want to refresh the environment, clean off the desktop, reset shortcuts pinned to the task bar for the next session, etc. But I want to warn anyone sitting at the machine that this is about to happen. However, my scripts that use Balloontips very successfully as regular scripts don't work as scheduled jobs. They run, and I have verified they run as the user in question, by creating a Scheduled Job that rights a text file to the user desktop. But Balloon Tips don't actually appear. Is there some secret to getting this to work, or is this a form of "interaction" that a scheduled job just can't do?
I also tried an alternative approach, launching the browser with a web page warning of the impending cleanup. That also didn't work. Suggesting some limits to what can be done as a Scheduled Job.
I would much rather go the very "integrated with the OS" route of the balloon tips, but for the life of me it seems like that just isn't an option. So, any other suggestions for providing user info by way of a scheduled job?

Comment: In general scheduled jobs don't run where they have access to a users desktop/GUI

Comment: A Scheduled Job is stored and triggered as a Scheduled Task, and tasks run in something called Session 0 isolation - a kind of background desktop that the user can't see. This is why balloon tips/notify icons and the likes doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Since this runs in Session 0 where GUI interaction doesn't exist you must resort to some other mechanism.

You say this happens between sessions. You could show your ballon via another "notification script" that is executed from within your ScheduledJob. You have options here. For example:

- Add entry to registry Run key that will self delete on run. Shows popup when user logs in (session change ? ). Entry executes posh script which parameters you could craft, i.e. (`powershell -File notify.ps1 -ArgumentList "Operation bla bla.."`)
- Add ScheduledTask that doesn't run in Session 0 (regular task). You need to do that only once. Every next time you run this job to show notification to the user from within main script via  `schtasks run` or `ScheduledTasks` module depending on your system.
- Add a ScheduledTask that check periodically EventLog for the input of your main script. The task would start on logon and subscribe to event log notifications. I don't like this as the script must run non-stop.